# JarBundler on PC

Tags: java, macos, ant, jarbundler

I'm using the JarBundler ANT Task to create a `.app` for a client. It's possible to use it on PC, it requires the `JavaApplicationStub` from a mac. Is there anyway I can get this on a PC? I know it comes from the Apples release of Java, but that only comes as a `.dmg` and I can't get access to it. My question is where can I get this file so I can link to to the JarBundler ANT task, **or** is there another way to create a `.app` from a jar on a PC?

Comment: Why do you want to do this on a PC? .app bundles only work on a mac, and the JavaApplicationStub is just a default application that loads and runs a jar.

Comment: It's for a client, I wrote his Java app on my PC and want to bundle it into a .app for him.

Answer (score 0):

[JarBundler Ant](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) task is picking up `JavaApplicationStub` from

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

You could copy it from there.

Note: This is only working for Java 6 applications. For Java 7 applications you have to use [`AppBundler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) Ant Task from Oracle.

See also the accepted answer on the stack for the following question:

[Application is using Java 6 from Apple instead of Java 7 from Oracle on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15271448/287984)

Comment: I don't actually have the code for that project anymore, so I can't try out what you have said, sorry. I expect that file would be the one I would have needed, but my problem was how to get it on my pc.

Comment: Just stick it in a tar file and check it in your repository. On the PC you should handle it like any other 3rd party ressource in your build process. If you use `Ant` there is a `tar` task who is able to deal with tar files.