# Java 7 mac .app file "Unable to load Java Runtime Environment"

Tags: java, macos

I have problems with .app file. On empty mac os x mountain lion (10.8.4) on my app launch it asks java 6 to be installed.

**So first question would be why java 6? Why not java 7?** What is wrong with my app file?

Image: http://postimg.org/image/747o37od7/

It is created with appBundler.
build.xml

```
<project name="AppBundler" default="default" basedir=".">    

    <!-- <property environment="env" /> -->

    <taskdef name="bundleapp"
             classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"   
             classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />

    <target name="AppBundler">
        <bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
            name="AppBundler"
            displayname="AppBundler"
            identifier="lt.launcher.MacLauncher"
            mainclassname="lt.launcher.MacLauncher">
           <!-- <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" /> -->
            <classpath file="lib/launcher.jar" />

            <option value="-Xdock:icon=Contents/Resources/${bundle.icon}"/>

            <option value="-Dforce.new.vm=true"/>
            <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
            <option value="-Dforce.new.vm=true"/>
            <option value="-Dcom.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages=true"/>
            <option value="-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
            <option value="-Dcom.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name=AppBundler"/>
        </bundleapp>
    </target>

</project>
```

Info.plist:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>JavaAppLauncher</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>GenericApp.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>lt.launcher.MacLauncher</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>AppBundler</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>AppBundler</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string></string>
<key>JVMMainClassName</key>
<string>lt.launcher.MacLauncher</string>
<key>JVMOptions</key>
<array>
<string>-Xdock:icon=Contents/Resources/${bundle.icon}</string>
<string>-Dforce.new.vm=true</string>
<string>-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true</string>
<string>-Dforce.new.vm=true</string>
<string>-Dcom.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages=true</string>
<string>-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true</string>
<string>-Dcom.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name=AppBundler</string>
</array>
<key>JVMArguments</key>
<array>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**NOTE**: i don't want to bundle java inside app file. Because i don't think that it is a good practice to add it inside. When your .jar size is 1MB and app file will be 140+MB because of bundled java.

I am experimenting with appBundler and sometimes when i create .app file i get:

Image: http://postimg.org/image/6xxju2aw1/

**So another question would be how to create .app file which would require java 7 to be installed and on app launch if java 7 is not installed it would suggest you to download and install java 7?**

I have read a lot of tutorials/guides how to build .app file, but still not managed to make it work as i  want to.

**Any tips are welcome!**

[Application is using Java 6 from Apple instead of Java 7 from Oracle on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806709/application-is-using-java-6-from-apple-instead-of-java-7-from-oracle-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I believe you are getting that message because Java 6 was the last version of Java that Apple developed (development has been taken over by Oracle). If you're not willing to bundle a JRE, you will have to include a "ReadMe" file instructing the users how to download it Java 7, or alternatively maybe use WebStart.

Comment: I was hopping that where is a better solution.
I was analysing and found that in just installed mac os x mountain lion you will have "java" folders and preferences in System/Library/Java and in Library/Java...