# Unable to load Java Runtime Environment with embedded jre

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to bundle a java application on windows for mac using appbundler-1.0.jar and Ant with an embedded jre 7.

This is the build.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="AppName" default="default" basedir=".">
        <property environment="env" />
        <taskdef 
            name="bundleapp" 
            classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask" 
            classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />
        <target name="bundle-AppName">
            <bundleapp 
                outputdirectory="dist" 
                name="AppName" 
                displayname="AppName" 
                identifier="com.hmf.AppName" 
                icon="files\logo48.icns"
                shortversion="1.0"
                mainclassname="hmf.AppName.app">
                <classpath file="files/AppName.jar" />
                <librarypath dir="pathToLibraries" />
                <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=false"/>
                <option value="-XstartOnFirstThread=true"/>
                <option value="-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=false"/>
                <option value="-Dcom.apple.smallTabs=true"/>
                <option value="-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false"/>
                <option value="-Derby.storage.pageSize=8192"/>
                <option value="-Djava.library.path=lib/swt.jar:lib"/>
                <option value="-Xmx1400M"/>
            </bundleapp>
        </target>
    </project>
```

I then copy jre 7 for mac to PlugIns directory under AppName.app. (I cant make it work with the runtiime tag)

But when I try to run the application I get:
"Unable to load Java Runtime Environment".

When OS use system jre it works but I want to be able to use the embedded jre.

Also see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

[Application is using Java 6 from Apple instead of Java 7 from Oracle on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806709/application-is-using-java-6-from-apple-instead-of-java-7-from-oracle-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue with my "Unable to load Java Runtime Environment" by using an installed JDK as the jre to be embedded within my app.  I was until now using a jre unzipped within a user folder.  with the JDK I set the environment variable at the command line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I then used the

```
<runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
```

and it worked as the jre gets installed under the Plugins directory as it should i.e no need to manually copy jre

Comment: Are you able to do this when on a different operating system? I.e. creating an app for OSX from a windows machine?