# Pentaho Kettle + Neo4j jdbc driver error: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, kettle

I'm trying to use Pentaho Kettle 5.0.1A-stable with the Neo4j JDBC driver but when I try to preview the data of a "Table Input" step I get this error:

```
Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neo4j/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0)
```

Screenshot:
[image: Pentaho Kettle error when trying to preview the output of a "Table Input" step using Neo4j jdbc driver]

I have these lines in my .zshrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
export PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

- Java version is 1.7.0_60 (I'm using Mac OS X btw)
- I've cloned the Neo4j-driver and built it using Maven (last commit of the driver was   [5430d0454180a](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/commit/5430d0454180a9704093e02ebe6a068a843377ec) which added support to Neo4j 2.1.2)
- I built the driver with Maven with this command: mvn package
- I've copied the driver neo4j-jdbc-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies to the /lib dir in Kettle.

Any thoughts?

[They say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239393/929659) that this error usually happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime but I already set PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME so I'm running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but maybe some insight:

A major version of 51 corresponds to JDK 7 - that is in line with your description how you've built the Neo4j JDBC driver. Since Neo4j is based on JDK 7 and the JDBC Driver uses internally some of the Java 7 language features it is not possible to build it with a previous JDK.

It looks like kettle is using an earlier JDK version. Unfortunately I cannot give a advice how to force a specific JDK for Kettle. You might inspect your process list using `ps aux` and grep for kettle to see the full command being run.

Comment: Hi Stefan, that is exactly the case. Kettle is using the Mac's JDK 1.6.0 hence the error.  Thank you for the prompt response :)  I'll need to find a way to get Kettle running with Java 7.

Comment: ok, [I've found the root of all evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15271448/929659) It's related to the way Java apps are bundled for Mac: this is a dead end.

Comment: I got Kettle running on Java 7 by executing `./spoon.command` in my case it is located in `/Applications/data-integration/spoon.command` :)